# Can't delete folder with ? in permissions

Tags: permissions, mount

I have a mount point where a USB drive is usually mounted. The USB drive is currently disconnected. If I try to attach it, it won't mount, and a bit of investigation discovered there's nothing wrong with the USB drive, but the mount point.

```
alan@hal:~$ ls -l /media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2 
ls: cannot access '/media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2': Input/output error
```

```
alan@hal:~$ ls -l /media/alan/
ls: cannot access '/media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2': Input/output error
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2
```

```
alan@hal:~$ sudo rm -rf /media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2 
rm: cannot remove '/media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2': Is a directory
```

```
alan@hal:~$ sudo chmod 600 /media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2 
chmod: cannot access '/media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2': Input/output error
```

How can I remove this directory?

Edit: Surprisingly `sudo umount /media/alan/9098a06f-f509-452a-b2b8-3f00aee808a2` removed it!? However, every time I re-attach the disk, I still get IO errors.

Comment: I/O is error might be the sign of a failing device. Are you sure the device is okay physically?

Comment: Looks like there are two possibilities:

1. You have read but not execute permissions on the directory you want to delete, or its parent directory.
2. Your disk is failing/has failed.

Comment: can you check the attributes on the catalogue? lsattr

Comment: Internal disk otherwise seems fine. I'm not convinced there's a disk failure as everything else is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but I once had a very similar problem. Turned out the file manager RANGER could handle it (not sure why)

Ranger is not user friendly, basically launch it via command line (ranger, once its installed) and then use arrow keys (or vim keys) to navigate to the folder you are trying to delete, press 'Shift d' (uppercase D) and then hit enter, should remove the folder)

good luck :)

Comment: Never tried Ranger, will try it :)